# Issue in the order of display of Arabic texts in PDF file generated using ColdFusion

Tags: css, pdf, unicode, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a query result set as given below.

[image]
I want to display details from this query in a pattern of name1 amount1  unit1,name2 amount2 unit2,name3 amount3 unit3,name4 amount4 unit 4 and that too in RTL (Right To Left) direction since data from the query is Arabic.

For example : please see the screen shot of pdf file.
[image]

**Issue:** Order of Arabic text is not correct as expected as given in the above screenshot. Below is the code snippet I used to generate pdf but order of display is wrong.

```
<cfset local.qBuckets = QueryNew("amount,name,unit","varchar,varchar,varchar") />
<cfset Queryaddrow(local.qBuckets,4)>
<cfset x=1>
<cfset Querysetcell(local.qBuckets,'amount','غير محدودة',x)>
<cfset Querysetcell(local.qBuckets,'name','لبيانات المحلية والعالمية',x)>
<cfset Querysetcell(local.qBuckets,'unit','جيجابايت',x)>
<cfset y=2>
<cfset Querysetcell(local.qBuckets,'amount','600',y)>
<cfset Querysetcell(local.qBuckets,'name','الدولية',y)>
<cfset Querysetcell(local.qBuckets,'unit','دقيقة',y)>
<cfset z=3>
<cfset Querysetcell(local.qBuckets,'amount','300',z)>
<cfset Querysetcell(local.qBuckets,'name','التجوال الوارد',z)>
<cfset Querysetcell(local.qBuckets,'unit','دقيقة',z)>
<cfset p=4>
<cfset Querysetcell(local.qBuckets,'amount','غير محدودة',p)>
<cfset Querysetcell(local.qBuckets,'name','المكالمات المحلية / الرسائل القصيرة',p)>
<cfset Querysetcell(local.qBuckets,'unit','جيجابايت',p)>

<cfoutput>
<cfdocument filename="c:\arr-bill.pdf" format="pdf" overwrite="true">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="center" style="width:190mm;direction: rtl;">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom:1pt solid ##000000;">
            <span style="font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold;">Red 750</span>
            <BR />
            <span style="font-size:9pt;">
                <cfset attributes.bucketSep = "">
                <cfloop query="local.qBuckets">
                    #attributes.bucketSep# <span style="font-weight: bold;color:black;">#name#</span>
                    #amount# #unit#
                    <cfset attributes.bucketSep = ",">
                </cfloop>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</cfdocument>
</cfoutput>
```

**Notes:** Order of Arabic text is correct in HTML output (in browser). Also , the order is correct in pdf file but only when I remove the span used around the name.

**PDF generating code where order is corret**

```
<cfdocument filename="c:\arr-bill.pdf" format="pdf" overwrite="true">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="center" style="width:190mm;direction: rtl;">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom:1pt solid ##000000;">
            <span style="font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold;">Red 750</span>
            <BR />
            <span style="font-size:9pt;">
                <cfset attributes.bucketSep = "">
                <cfloop query="local.qBuckets">
                    #attributes.bucketSep# #name#
                    #amount# #unit#
                    <cfset attributes.bucketSep = ",">
                </cfloop>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</cfdocument>
```

Comment: Does the query providing this data have an order by clause?

Comment: No... I can make this more simple. Suppose we have two variables with some arabic texts assigned to it and i want to combine these two arabic texts in pdf.<cfset x="," />
   <cfset a1='االبيانات احلية والعاية غير دود غيغابايت' />
   <cfset b1='الدولية 600 دقيقة' />
   <span style="font-size:9pt;"><span>#a1#</span> #x# #b1#</span>
   <BR />

When I remove the "span" used around the "a1" variable I can combine the variables a1 and b1 with a comma(x) and show in pdf correctly. But when i use that span then I am not able to do that and in pdf I am getting a different comination of a1 and b1.

Comment: Not an RTL expert here, but I assume the `<span>` interrupts the text flow. And if the browser cannot detect the text direction automatically, it defaults to LTR. Did you [specify CSS direction](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_direction&preval=rtl)?

Comment: Yes , span interrupts the text flow. In browser it is working fine no "span" interruption , but its not working in PDF. To answer your last question , Yes I had specified the direction(RTL) for the table but not for the span. I had tried by specifying the direction for span as well but no luck.

Comment: I just checked, docs of `<cfdocument>` do not state support for CSS style `direction`, so you might be out of luck here.

Comment: if it doesnt support then how it is working fine when i remove the span used around the "name". You can test this by executing the code I have given above under the heading "PDF generating code where order is correct".